# Cannot find symbol in Java, GreenFoot

Tags: java, methods, greenfoot

Before I start, I'd like to mention that I'm new to programming and I'm really bad. If you can think of ANY reason as to what may be causing my issue, it's probably worth checking.

I'm making a game where the user controls a shark and has to move around, eating the fish and dodging the trash. The user gets a point whenever they eat a fish. I've been having an issue where the program says it can't find a method and I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is where the error is. It's in the Food class (the fish, what the shark eats):

```
Actor foodHit = getOneIntersectingObject(Shark.class);
  if(foodHit!=null)
  {
    World MyWorld = (World)MyWorld;
    Counter counter = World.getCounter(); 
    // The error is apparently in this line above, here's the error code: "cannot find symbol -  method getCounter()".
    counter.addScore();
    MyWorld.removeObject(this);
  }
```

This is the method in question, it is in the MyWorld class:

```
public Counter getCounter()
{
  return counter;
}
```

I can answer any questions and show more lines if you request.
I know it's frustrating to deal with new people sometimes so I'm sorry in advance.
Any help would be amazing, thanks for reading!

Comment: You are working in Java, not JavaScript btw :)

Comment: Since you are new to programming, it's possible you are expecting the Food class to be able to reference the shark's world globally. What are you doing here: `World MyWorld = (World)MyWorld;`  What type is MyWorld before you cast it to World?

Comment: I was following an instructional video where they typed that. I do not understand what that line is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `World` base class and a `MyWorld` class that extends `World` and the `getCounter()` method is in the derived `MyWorld` class, then `getCounter()` will not be "visible" after you cast a `MyWorld` type object to a `World` type object.  `getCounter()` only exists "in" `MyWorld` type objects.
(and casting in that direction isn't required anyway. Instances of `MyWorld` are also instances of `World`, no cast required.  But instances of `World` may or may not also be instances of `MyWorld`, cast to `MyWorld` required in order to call methods defined in `MyWorld`)

Also, it's standard in Java to start variable names with lower case and class names with upper case.  So a reader of your code would typically expect `MyWorld` to be a class name (an object type name) and `myWorld` to be a variable name (an object instance name).

I guess since you are copying code from a video you should do what they do so you can follow along with the video more easily.  But if I were coding this, I would want to put an eatFood() method on the Shark class so that I could write

```
if (foodHit != null) {
    aShark.eatFood()
}
```

that way the world casting and counter updating code is encapsulated inside the Shark class rather than scattered around everywhere you check for food hits.

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you change the code.

From

```
World MyWorld = (World)MyWorld;
Counter counter = World.getCounter();
```

To

```
World MyWorld = (World)MyWorld;
Counter counter = MyWorld.getCounter();
```

That should fix it. I had to post an answer since I don't have enough rep to comment. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same error, as if the method is not in either of the 2 actors. Would it help if i sent the whole Greenfoot project to you?

Comment: Yeah, that would make it easier for me to help you.